# Excel related query

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bulk of data in this form as shown below in example

```
**Staff ID/name     Date        ID**
2586 Ali Husnain        
                   26-Jan-16    762889
                   26-Jan-16    762889
2588 Jabbar Ahmad       
                   23-Jan-16    762209
                   23-Jan-16    762209
2617 Walayat Ali        
                   10-Feb-16    765307
2620 Muhammad Azam      
                   6-Feb-16     764374
                   6-Feb-16     764374
2664 Maqsood Ahmed      
                   23-Jan-16    762207
                   23-Jan-16    762207
                   23-Jan-16    762207
                   23-Jan-16    762207
```

Now I want to Arrange in it in this format i.e.

```
**Date        ID     Staff ID/name** 
26-Jan-16   762889  2586Ali Husnain
26-Jan-16   762889  2586Ali Husnain

23-Jan-16   762209  2588Jabbar Ahmad
23-Jan-16   762209  2588Jabbar Ahmad

10-Feb-16   765307  2617Walayat Ali

6-Feb-16    764374  2620Muhammad Azam
6-Feb-16    764374  2620Muhammad Azam

23-Jan-16   762207  2664Maqsood Ahmed
23-Jan-16   762207  2664Maqsood Ahmed
23-Jan-16   762207  2664Maqsood Ahmed
23-Jan-16   762207  2664Maqsood Ahmed
```

Currently i have to copy staff ID/name one by one and have to paste in front of its relevant date and ID column.......
I have a huge bulk of data can i obtain the desired result using some excel formula or command.
Hope it clarify now

Comment: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html  Do this on the first column, then copy/paste values, then delete the unwanted rows.

Comment: Thank you very much ......it really works

Answer (score 1):

What you want in a result column beside your table is ...

- if column B is empty, it is a name record and you want a blank in column D, else it is a data row and you want [*something*] in D --> `=IF(B[x]="","",[something])`
- we now say following about the [*something*]: if in column D a blank appears in the row above current (like delivered in step 1 above), use the name from column A in row above, else use the name from column D in row above --> `=IF(D[x-1]="",A[x-1],D[x-1])`
- nesting the two conditions into one formula for D3: `=IF(B3="","",IF(D2="",A2,D2))` (and copy down)

Example

[image]

Now you can post process your table by by converting formulas into values, filter and delete rows containing blanks in column D, etc. etc.